# Pylint in Neovim using Mason and null-ls cannot load packages

Tags: python, macos, pylint, neovim, pythonpath

I was hoping you would be able to help me get pylint fully functional in nvim.

Env:
Mac OS Venture 13.1
nvim v0.8.1
pylint 2.15.9
python 3.11.1 (accessed through 'python3')
pip 22.3.1 (accessed through 'pip3')
I am using the latest versions of null-ls and Mason and the related libraries to tie all of this together.

My problem is that pylint does not recognise any of the packages I have fetched with pip3. My code executes as expected when I run it using python3, so the packages are installed and the modules are loaded correctly. I have checked :Mason in nvim and it has access to the right python and pip executables.

If I install pylint outside Neovim, it gives me the same error. I can correct it by running it with --init-hook="import sys; sys.path.append('/Library/Fr...)" which points to the directory where pip3 saves the packages that are installed.

How do I check which paths pylint uses to search for packages to import? And how can I neatly add the right paths to direct it to the correct place?

I seem to be missing some fundamental piece of information to understand the problem. Any ideas?

Thank you all so much for the help and support! <3 And I look forward to continue my coding journey!

Comment: Can you show the outcome of `:checkhealth provider`

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled pylint using mason and that fixed it for me.